# AJAX Error with $_POST -> Post is not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I just can't find the mistake here: I want to create a very simple ajax request and write it via the $_post method (without $.ajax in the beginning):

```
$(function() {
$('#class1dropdown').change(function()
{
var self = $(this);

$_post("/partials/choosesubject1.php",
{
klasse1: self.val()
},
function(data)
{
    $('#subjects1').html(data);
});

});
});
```

But the console always says:

```
ReferenceError: $_post is not defined
```

Now I know that means that $_post is not defined, but how and why?? I literally checked it a hundred times and compared it to my other code for sending an ajax request, which works perfectly:

```
 $(function() {
 $('#class1dropdown').change(function()
 {
var self = $(this);

$.ajax({
    url: '/partials/choosesubject1.php',        
    type: 'POST',
    data: { klasse1: self.val() },
    success: function(data){
      $('#subjects1').html(data);
    }
});
});
});
```

Comment: Their is not `$._post` change it with `$.post`.

Comment: Ooooh.. thank you! Stupid me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is not `$._post` change it with `$.post`.

```
$(function () {
    $('#class1dropdown').change(function () {
        var self = $(this);

        //change made here  
        $.post("/partials/choosesubject1.php",
        {
            klasse1: self.val()
        },
        function (data) {
            $('#subjects1').html(data);
        });

    });
});
```